# FWER adjustment

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, subsampling

I want to use the built-in `ToothGrowth` dataset in `R` to write an assignment and conduct `t.test`s. The dataset has three columns and 60 rows and, for each observation, it contains the supplement given to a guinea pin which is OJ (orange juice) or VC (vitamin C), the length of tooth growth in a specified period of time and in the last column the dose in mg.

I want to separate the database into two smaller sets to conduct a `t.test` to see if the raise in dose affects the tooth length per supplement separately and then conduct a `t.test` to test the difference in means between supplement OJ and VC with response to tooth length as a whole and `t.tests` to see the difference between OJ and VC keeping the dose constant for both.

Should I use the Bonferroni adjustment for all the $p$-values or do something else? These are 10 tests, but 9 of them concern specific subsamples of the original dataset.

Comment: The need to correct for multiple testing depends on the purpose of the analysis and the types of inference that it is intended to make. In other words, you may not need to make any adjustments to p-values or to critical regions. (And if you do need to adjust then the Bonferroni is likely not the best choice.) What is you analysis for, and what inferences would you like to be able to make?

Comment: this is an assignment but nontheless even with Benjamini Hochberg correction, do I have to adjust for all the p-values? since the sample size and nature of tests changes.

Comment: A thoughtful commentary on the relationship between analytical goals and analytic methods would be a great response to the assignment! Yeah, I know, maybe risky. I don't know which p-values (or critical regions) your instructor might expect to be adjusted, but I suggest you think about which tests belong to separate families from the point of view of your inferences.